# Bind a datatable with user defined header in an existing excelsheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

i Have tried to merge a header which will be placed on top of my datatable and the it will cover full column length of my datatable as well.
Every Sheet Will Contain Table Name as SheetName

Like The Following
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jk8D.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelExport
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExportExcelSheet();
        }
        public void ExportExcelSheet()
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            string TableName = "tblCompanies";
            using (ExcelExporter objExcelExporter = new ExcelExporter())
            {
                objExcelExporter.TableName = TableName;
                dt = objExcelExporter.GetAllRecords();
            }

            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "MergeSQLTest.xlsx";
            try
            {
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
                xlWorkSheet = xlApp.Workbooks[1].Worksheets["Sheet1"];

                xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                Excel.Range cell = xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Cells;
                var col = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns["A:G", Type.Missing];
                cell = xlWorkSheet.Range["A1:G6"];
                cell.Value2 = "Table Column Information";
                cell.Merge();


                xlWorkBook.SaveAs(path, AccessMode: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared);

                xlApp.Workbooks[1].Close();

                xlWorkBook.Close(0);
                xlApp.Quit();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                xlWorkBook.Close(0);
                xlApp.Quit(); xlApp.Quit();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Getting error could you please try